# Can you use arithmetic on two or more specific elements of an array without a loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am simply trying to add two numbers from an array here is the code I am using which is only concatenating the two.

```
if (this.id == "=") {
        if (HYUTS[1] == '+') {
            var sum = HYUTS[0] + HYUTS[2];
            alert(sum);
        }
    }
```

Comment: If the `+` operator is concatenating the elements, then that means the elements are strings and not numbers.

Comment: var sum = +HYUTS[0] + +HYUTS[2]; converts them to number

Comment: That was it @juvian thank you!

Comment: var sum = Number(HYUTS[0]) + Number(HYUTS[2]); also works if you want something more explicit.  Using the + operator to cast as an int makes it a little harder tell between intentionally casting and a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (this.id == "=") {
        if (HYUTS[1] == '+') {
            var sum = +HYUTS[0] + +HYUTS[2];
            alert(sum);
        }
    }
```

This means that the `HYUTS[0]` and `HYUTS[2]` are `strings` and not `int`, do `+HYUTS[0]` to convert them to `int`.

Comment: Thank you that was it! @void

Comment: Definitely will confirm it as right answer, guess I have to wait 10 minutes though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Number function if you has values as string in array

```
if (this.id == "=") {
    if (HYUTS[1] == '+') {
        var sum = Number(HYUTS[0]) + Number(HYUTS[2]);
        alert(sum);
    }
}
```